# Update current instance of Window from another class, rather than the newly created C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to use BeginAnimation on the current instance of a Window, but nothings happening because its using the instance that I have just created.

I've read in other answers to use DataContext, but those answers were targeted at accessing properties for textboxes, and I don't think it applies here.

EditSql.xaml.cs

```
    {
        MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
        e.Cancel = true;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        main.RestoreAfterEditClose();
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    public void RestoreAfterEditClose()
    {
        Grid2.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, instant1);    // not working
        this.ManageGrid.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, instant1);   // not working
        Create_A_Visit.Foreground = Brushes.Red; // not working
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

I know the issue is that it's starting the animation on the newly created `main` instead of the current instance but not sure how to fix. This is probably bread and butter stuff, but it would be good to have a good understanding of how this works going forward.

EDIT

The issue is this, because I'm creating a new instance of MainWindow called `main`, when I call the class `RestoreAfterEditClose` as `main.RestoreAfterEditClose()`it's not taking effect on my previous MainWindow that is hidden (Obviously, I've proved this by doing main.Show(), and saw the changes took affect there).

To try clarify exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to find a way to call `RestoreAfterEditClose` on my current instance of the MainWindow from a different class but I don't know how.

Question: Is there anyway to call the a method on another class without creating a new instance of MainWindow?

Full Method

EditSql.xaml.cs

```
    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
        main.Show();
        main.RestoreAfterEditClose();
        e.Cancel = true;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;         
    }
```

Comment: Your `MainWindow`. is still `Hidden`. It must be `Visible` to see the `Opacity ` changes.

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing. You must call `main.Show()` to make the new instance visible.

Comment: What is `instant1`? Please provide the full context. Don't start a quiz show here.

Comment: @BionicCode I've added an edit. `instant1` simply changes the opacity to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call RestoreAfterEditClose on the new Window. If you want to do it on another window, you have to call it there.

You can access the current main window with `((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow)` or by getting the parent window of a control: `Window.GetWindow(this)`.

Comment: I've tried the above, and still nothing. To clarify, I'm calling `RestoreAfterEditClose()` on my the window `EditSQL`, but none of the animations start on `MainWindow`.  Am I misunderstanding your solution?

Comment: Then instant1 must be wrong. That must be the instance you want to do the animations on. As this is a method on a window, it would be logic it is 'this', or a control of 'this'.

Comment: As I explained in my answer, there are several methods to access the main window. Just call the method on the right window, instead of creating a new window you don't need.
I propose to look up some basic C# tutorials online to understand the concepts of instances of a class. You will lose much more time in trying and failing if you don't.

Comment: Yeah I'm not creating a Window I don't need. The Window is in use, the full class is an event on when the Window closes. I'll mark your answer as correct anyways, I'll just find another way of doing it.

Comment: I've added the full method at the bottom

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want to do an animation on the window that's closing (the window raising the Window_Closing event)?

Comment: I want the animation to start on the MainWindow, after the Window closes on the another. I fixed the whole issue by just adding an event handler to the MainWindow class to listen for when the event `Window_Closing` on the other